# Do we have to insert the DC null in OFDM when using RF direct sampling ADC architecture?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, analog-to-digital, software-defined-radio

Generally, DC Nulls are added in OFDM because zero-IF receivers don't pass the DC component. But what if I use an RF direct sampling architecture? Will there be DC offset? If not, then is it okay not to insert a DC null?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> RF direct sampling architecture?
> Will there be DC offset?

No, since the center of your signal doesn't end up on DC, so there's no DC offset.

> If not, then is it okay not to insert a DC null?

yes.

However, you might want to use quadrature mixers for the other end, so you might not want to do that.

Also note that instead of direct sampling, superhet / low-IF approaches can also get rid of the DC offset, as does, to a not-so-bad degree, calibration. The question whether you need to insert a zero carrier at the center frequency of your OFDM signal is often a complex, more systemic one than just looking at the receiver architecture.